# wait for apicall to be done, before continue

Tags: swift, api

I am new to swift, and since I work as a backend developer, I thought I would try to make a app,
to understand how the data I return from the api I make, is handled. I also do front end sometimes, but it is on the website :D

In c# I know of async/await which can make the code wait to get a result, before continuing. I have tried with completetion handlers, and group.enter(), group.leave(), which didn't work, or I didn't do it right. I know asynce/await isnt a thing yet, in swift, or so did I read.

Here is my code, I have right now:

```
struct vuItem:Decodable {
var date:String
var temperatureC:Int
var temperatureF:Int
var summary:String

}
var vuItems:[vuItem] = [vuItem]()

func getVejr() -> [vuItem] {

let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.137.1:90/weatherforecast")
var result = [vuItem]()
let session = URLSession.shared

let task = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    // Check the response
    print(error)
    print(response)
    do {
        result = try! JSONDecoder().decode([vuItem].self, from: data!)
        print(result[0].date)
    }
    })
    task.resume()
    return result
}

vuItems = getVejr()

vuItems.forEach { (item) in
    print(item.date)
}
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve

Comment: @LucaSfragara I am trying to make it wait for "getVejr()" is done, and have returned a result, before continuing the cide

Comment: @Rob It is playground

Comment: *Don't ask, tell*. Use an asynchronous completion handler